# jQuery trigger only occurs first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Clicking `#input` multiple times will upload a file each time.

Clicking `#button` which in turn triggers `#input` will only upload a file the first time (and not at all if `#input` was first clicked).  I will, however, open the file selector browser, just not upload the file.

Why is this, and how do I change it to allow it to be clicked multiple times?

PS.  Why I wish to do so instead of just using an `#input`?  I am using jQueryUI Dialog and wish one of the buttons to initiate the input.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My profile</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $('#button').click(function(){uploader.trigger('click');});
                var uploader=$('#input').fileupload( {
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    formData: {user_id:50},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button">Click</button>
        <input id="input" type="file" name="name">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I think, there should be a change in the order where you first initialize the variable `uploader` and where you register the `click` event on the `#button`.

**Update**

Meanwhile, initiating the `uploader` variable upon clicking `#button` each time should solve the problem:

```
$(function(){
            $('#button').click(function(){
                var uploader=$('#input').fileupload( {
                url: 'upload.php',
                formData: {user_id:50},
                dataType: 'json',
                });
                uploader.trigger('click');
             });
        });
```

Comment: No change in behavior.

Comment: @user1032531, can you check the updated answer to see what happens.

Comment: Seems to work.  As a matter of principle, it seems like it shouldn't be necessary.  Thank you

Comment: @user1032531, welcome. Don't forget the +1/Accept :)

Comment: Re-initializing the plugin is causing other problems, and I think I need to find another solution.

Comment: Can you be specific on what problems it's causing.