# Position button element directly over input element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can I make `#input` the same size as `#button`, and position `#button` directly over `#input`?

[image]

https://jsbin.com/lovorisope

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="input" type="file" name="bla" />

        <br><br>

        <button id="button" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Upload</span>
        </button>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to. You can have the button trigger the input button using javascript. The input can be invisible for that matter.

Comment: @lbu is right...its like your are trying to do something unnecessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679611/jquery-trigger-only-occurs-first-time/32679722?noredirect=1#comment53204130_32679722. Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using JQuery posted a solution using it.

Have a look at this:

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#input').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="file" name="bla" hidden/>
<button id="button" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"> <span class="ui-button-text">Choose File</span>

</button>
```

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p758c7tx/1/)

> Note : I would suggest to give custom named class/id to both the `input` & `button`, so all the same elements in your page would not get conflicted. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p758c7tx/2/).

.

**THE UPDATE**

Solution **without using .trigger() & .click()**.

Here i have gathered the `left` + `top` positions of button along with it's `height` + `width`.  Which is used to position the `input` field using **JQuery** plugin `.CSS`

Just as i mentioned above you will **need to give custom names** to classes'/ids' of  this couple(button & input) to make this work.

```js
var btn_h = $(".upload_btn").outerHeight(); 
var btn_w = $(".upload_btn").outerWidth();

var top_pos = $(".upload_btn").position().top;
var left_pos = $(".upload_btn").position().left;

$(".cust_btn").css({
         height: btn_h + "px",
         width: btn_w + "px",    
         top: top_pos + "px",  
         left: left_pos + "px"
});
```

```css
.cust_btn
{
    position:absolute;
    background:lightgrey;
    z-index:9999;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Added class upload_btn -->
<button id="button" type="button" class="upload_btn ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button"> <span class="ui-button-text">Choose File</span>
</button>
<input id="input" class="hidden_input cust_btn" type="file" name="bla" />
```

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p758c7tx/3/)

If you wan to see where this `input` exactly is change opacity to `opacity:.5`. **Once again** you will need to give your own class/id name.

Comment: For reasons unknown to me, `trigger` doesn't work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679611/jquery-trigger-only-occurs-first-time/32679722?noredirect=1#comment53204130_32679722.  As such, I was trying a different solution.

Comment: @user1032531 Could you try `.click()` instead of `.trigger()`. Like `$('#input').click();`.  Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: According to the documentation, doing so is not very cross browser compatible.

Comment: Ya i know that but, i don't think of anything else for now.

Comment: I've been attempting to replace the dialog button with an input and style the input like the jquery buttons.  Close but not working.  I posted it as an answer even though it is a crappy answer.  Can you take a look?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Divy.  I will take a look after dinner.  Do you know if it will work when replacing jQueryUI dialog buttons?

Comment: Replacing with some other UI?

Comment: Replacing jQueryUI dialog buttons similar to https://jsbin.com/qejivarixa/edit?html,output.

Comment: Yes replacing it would not cause any issues. It will always work.

Comment: Even if you want that button in some div that has lot's of vertical scroll, still it would work but add `position` as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p758c7tx/5/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to customize the file upload button, why not doing it as below :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">
            .fileUpload {
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            .fileUpload input.upload {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-size: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                opacity: 0;
                filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
            <span>Upload</span>
            <input type="file" class="upload" />
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Take a look here : http://goo.gl/A74FLi

Comment: If I do this and ever change the jQueryUI theme, the button will not match.  Is there anyway to make it transparent and just fit over the jQueryUI dialog button?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work and is not an acceptable answer. Just posting it as a possible idea...

https://jsbin.com/qejivarixa/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.7/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                var dialog = $('<div/>').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    create: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#_upload" ).wrap( $("<div />",{style:'position: relative;overflow: hidden;width:100px'})).after(
                            $('<input/>',{
                                type:'file',
                                name:'bla',
                                style:'position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-size: 20px;cursor: pointer;opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);',
                            }).fileupload()
                        );
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            id:'_upload',
                            text: 'Upload',
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Save',
                            disabled: true,
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                        }
                    ]
                });                
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body> 
</html>
```

Comment: So you saying, that this does not open browse-files dialog on click?

Comment: @divy3993  It does open the browser on click.  It just positions the buttons crazy.

Comment: I have got it. Got solution for you but it's little tricky should i post as new Answer?